# From a question to a noun clause

Tags: grammar, nouns, questions

How to change this question “What does it do?” Into a noun clause?

Which one is correct?
- what it does.
- what it do.

( with an explanation, if it’s possible) 
Thakn you

Answer (score 1):

I will use "what it does". According to the Subject-Verb Agreement rule, the subject "it"is the third-person, so you should use the singular verb.
For example, you change the question: "where does she live?" in to Nouns clause :"I want to know where she lives. You put singular verb after the subject.